# Is there a way to get the socket descriptor of the started VPN Tunnel on iPhone so that I could use it in a C++ library

Tags: ios, sockets, tcp, vpn, tunnel

In the ***simpleTunnel*** sample app provided by apple, the container app and the packet tunnel provider use IPC for communication.

Whenever connect toggle button is enabled **startVPNTunnel()** API will be called and the OS starts the packet tunnel provider which in turn calls the overrided method **startTunnelWithOptions()**. This is where we start our connection to the VPN server. **startTunnelWithOptions** in turn calls **startTunnel** which calls **createTCPConnectionToEndpoint** (***connection = provider.createTCPConnectionToEndpoint(endpoint, enableTLS:false, TLSParameters:nil, delegate:nil)***)

How do we get the socket descriptor from this connection (so that I could use it in another C++ library that sends SSL and other custom messages) ?
(connnection is an instance of the class **NWTCPConnection**, but **NWTCPConnection** doesn't seem to contain the socket descriptor)

Comment: **See also [How to parse network-extension packets?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69487795/8740349)**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure I understood you, but if you are looking for the socket's file descriptor - you can't get it.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like:

```
let tunFd = self.packetFlow.value(forKeyPath: "socket.fileDescriptor") as! Int32;
```

And send `tunFd` to your C/C++ side to use as file-descriptor and/or socket.

See also [How to parse network-extension packets?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69487795/8740349)

> **Note** that although Apple recommends against using this method in production, it's end-year 2021, and works just fine yet.
>
> Apple [claims](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/13503) that
> "iOS is in the process of moving to a user space networking stack."
> (but they did not change anything yet)

Answer (score 0):

I haven't seen a way to get a socket out of it. That's the whole reason why they expose high level API read/write/cancel on `NWTCPConnection`.

However, `createTCPConnectionToEndpoint` isn't required. It's just a convenience method. You can do everything on a socket level and ignore this API (if it works better for you).