# iOS network extension packet parsing

Tags: ios, vpn, networkextension

I am developing a VPN (iOS Network Extension), and using C/C++ to read file-descriptor directly (instead of Swift), currently it successfully captures device's request Packets, but I don't know how to parse iOS's packets, I could not even find what network layer or protocol the packets are formatted in.

I converted Packet's binary into Hex to be able to decode with online tools; below are samples of what I need to parse:

```
000000024500003B5461000040110C390A07000208080808FA2D0035002739B4DE790100000100000000000003777777056170706C6503636F6D0000010001

000000024500003CBAE200004011A5B60A07000208080808E48A0035002892DAE43B01000001000000000000037777770669636C6F756403636F6D0000010001

00000002450000375324000040110D7A0A07000208080808DD7F003500232BBA841801000001000000000000056170706C6503636F6D0000010001
```

But when tried parsing with [online decoder](https://hpd.gasmi.net), they fail saying invalid packet.

**What network layer or protocol is above?**

> **Note** that above are 3 packet samples (not one splitted by me).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### It's `tun`-layer protocol with `4` bytes prefix:

1. Once we use C/C++ to read file-descriptor, in `NEPacketTunnelProvider` like:

```
let tunFd = self.packetFlow.value(forKeyPath: "socket.fileDescriptor") as! Int32

// ... pass above to C/C++ backend
```

Instead of using `Swift` like:

```
self.packetFlow.readPackets { [weak self] (packets: [Data], protocols: [NSNumber]) in
    // Handle packets here...
}
```

2. There are `4` additional bytes prefixed to the `tun-layer` packet (e.g. `00 00 00 02`), each time we read packets.

3. To allow most online-tools  to understand the packet, remove those starting `4` bytes, and instead prefix it with Mac-Header-Hex like:

```
01 00 5E 00 00 09 C2 01 17 23 00 00 08 00
```

> **Note** that by doing above, we convert initial `tun`-layer packet to a `tap`-layer packet.
>
> Also, remember to prefix again those `4` bytes, once writing a packet into the file-descriptor (after removing Mac-Header).

---

**Update 2021;** Apple discourages accessing file-descriptor directly (and it may be removed in future iOS releases).

Comment: Although this fixed OP issue, to ensure our App doesn't get rejected, we migrated to the way Apple encourages (without accessing hidden variable).